# Conditional check per row, per group R

Tags: r, for-loop, conditional-statements

I am trying to check per group `week` if the value `x` is lower than value `y`. Per group only the first value `x` which is TRUE in `z` needs to be checked for all rows in that group, except the past days. Also, once the target value `expected` is TRUE, there is no need to further check for that `week`. (it is also fine to continue to check for that week if this critera causes extra complexity in the code).

Dataset:

```
date_daily <- seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-14"), by="days")
x <- c(4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 3)
y <- c(3, 4, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 2)
z <- c( FALSE,  TRUE ,  TRUE ,  FALSE ,  TRUE ,  FALSE ,  FALSE ,  FALSE ,  TRUE ,  TRUE ,  TRUE ,  
FALSE ,  TRUE ,  FALSE )
df <- data.frame(date_daily, x, y, z)
df$week <-  week(ymd(df$date_daily))
```

> ```
>    date_daily x y     z week
> 1  2020-01-01 4 3 FALSE    1
> 2  2020-01-02 5 4  TRUE    1
> 3  2020-01-03 5 6  TRUE    1
> 4  2020-01-04 7 6 FALSE    1
> 5  2020-01-05 7 5  TRUE    1
> 6  2020-01-06 8 5 FALSE    1
> 7  2020-01-07 6 5 FALSE    1
> 8  2020-01-08 3 2 FALSE    2
> 9  2020-01-09 4 3  TRUE    2
> 10 2020-01-10 4 4  TRUE    2
> 11 2020-01-11 5 5  TRUE    2
> 12 2020-01-12 5 7 FALSE    2
> 13 2020-01-13 6 5  TRUE    2
> 14 2020-01-14 3 2 FALSE    2
> ```

I tried `for loop` as a solution but had issues with the week group (would run for all rows). Expected outcome:

```
df$expected <- c(NA, FALSE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA)
```

> ```
>    date_daily x y     z week expected
> 1  2020-01-01 4 3 FALSE    1       NA
> 2  2020-01-02 5 4  TRUE    1    FALSE
> 3  2020-01-03 5 6  TRUE    1     TRUE
> 4  2020-01-04 7 6 FALSE    1       NA
> 5  2020-01-05 7 5  TRUE    1       NA
> 6  2020-01-06 8 5 FALSE    1       NA
> 7  2020-01-07 6 5 FALSE    1       NA
> 8  2020-01-08 3 2 FALSE    2       NA
> 9  2020-01-09 4 3  TRUE    2    FALSE
> 10 2020-01-10 4 4  TRUE    2    FALSE
> 11 2020-01-11 5 5  TRUE    2     TRUE
> 12 2020-01-12 5 7 FALSE    2       NA
> 13 2020-01-13 6 5  TRUE    2       NA
> 14 2020-01-14 3 2 FALSE    2       NA
> ```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[z, expected := cumsum(cumsum(x[z][1] < y)) == 1, week]
i1 <- df[, .I[seq_len(.N) > which(expected)], week]$V1
df[i1, expected := NA]
df
#    date_daily x y     z week expected
# 1: 2020-01-01 4 3 FALSE    1       NA
# 2: 2020-01-02 5 4  TRUE    1    FALSE
# 3: 2020-01-03 5 6  TRUE    1     TRUE
# 4: 2020-01-04 7 6 FALSE    1       NA
# 5: 2020-01-05 7 5  TRUE    1       NA
# 6: 2020-01-06 8 5 FALSE    1       NA
# 7: 2020-01-07 6 5 FALSE    1       NA
# 8: 2020-01-08 3 2 FALSE    2       NA
# 9: 2020-01-09 4 3  TRUE    2    FALSE
#10: 2020-01-10 4 4  TRUE    2    FALSE
#11: 2020-01-11 5 5  TRUE    2     TRUE
#12: 2020-01-12 5 7 FALSE    2       NA
#13: 2020-01-13 6 5  TRUE    2       NA
#14: 2020-01-14 3 2 FALSE    2       NA
```

Comment: Thanks, in case within a 'week' the 'expected' is every day 'FALSE', and I only want to keep the 'FALSE' of the last 'date_daily' of the 'week'. The previous 'FALSE' in that week should turn into NA. How should I approach that? (I am not experienced in the seq_len function).